# Why is my spatial join count 0 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

In arcMap, I have a list of locations with lat/long. From a previous post, I learned about the Spatial Join tool to determine the amount of joins that I have. I tried to use the tool with my states layer and it worked perfectly. However, when I tried to do it on the county layer, it is always giving me with 0 joins. What is the cause of this? The county layer that I am using is from http://www.gadm.org/. The one that I used for the states came from arcgis online. There was one for the countries, but it would give me an error when trying to do a spatial join on the data.

Comment: What projection(s) are the data in?

Comment: The coordinates are in GCS_WGS_1984 and the county layer is in GCS_WGS_1984

Comment: what happens when you load the county layer and the coordinates in a fresh new mxd, do they overlay (just these two layers in a new arcmap session)

Comment: My points overlay on the county layer.

Comment: Alright, I did a spatial join on the new mxd and it is showing the joins correctly. I don't know what I did differently.

Comment: Sounds like you may have had a selection on your data and as tools always use selections first you may have had a scenario where the selection had no spatial relation as defined in your join criteria?

Comment: I added the comment as an answer below as it resolved your issue.

Comment: Not sure why you got down-voted it seem harsh. I up-voted it back to zero. Do not let that stop you from using the stack.

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine, questions are upvoted/downvoted based on how useful others deem them. As this question boils down to a simple restart of the app, it provides little benefit.

Comment: Well I think that the understanding of what is going on in map frames is actually vitally important. It is the understanding of why the new mxd works as opposed to the actual generation of the mxd that is key.

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you load the county layer and the coordinates in a fresh new mxd, do they overlay (just these two layers in a new arcmap session)?

Ok so this worked. Likely a different projection in the TOC / Map or a selection issue..